# Calling a method within another method - Javascript class object

Tags: javascript, function, class, methods

The following is my ***javascript*** code

```
class Sample {
   constructor() {
       this.btn = document.getElementById("btn");
       this.score_display = document.getElementById("display");
       this.current_container = document.getElementById("current_container);
       this.next_container = document.getElementById("next_container);
       this.scores = document.querySelectorAll(".scores")

       this.finalScore;   //final score 


       // Event listeners
        this.eventListeners();
    }

    eventListeners() {
        this.btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            this.next_container.classList.remove('hidden');
            this.current_container.classList.add('hidden');
            
            this.getScores();
        });
    }

    getScores() {
       this.scores.forEach(score => {
            this. finalScore = 
            this.scores_display.innerHTML = this.score;
      });
   }
}
```

In the example code above, there are

1. current container (rating app) - which has the rating/stars to be selected
2. next container - that displays the selected rating/score from the current container
3. When button is clicked, 'hidden' class is added to current container and removed from next.
4. getScores() computes the scores and assigns to the finalScore
5. Finallt, getScores() is called int he eventlistener.

The problem is, when I click btn(with eventlistener), the next_container, where the output of getScore() is to be stored, loads up very quickly before the getScore() is executed. This results in getScore() undefined.

I could manage this, by calling getScores() in the contructor so that it automatically is called, thus making a value of finalScore() available when the next_container is loaded.

How I can achieve this without the method called in the contructor

*** Edit ***

I have added the *codepen* link below

***https://codepen.io/ajithtemp/pen/XWqzKoZ?editors=1111***

Comment: What do you mean by "loads up very quickly"? There's nothing in your code that loads anything.

Comment: BTW `this.scores_display.innerHTML = this.score;` <-- This is a potential XSS vulnerability. Is there a (good) reason why you're not setting `textContent` instead?

Comment: Why can't you just set `this.finalScore = null` in your constructor?

Comment: @Dai - when I click on the submit button,  current_container is hidden and next_container appears. In the next container, I have a p tag that displays the selection (value) from the current container. But, when I press the button, it immediately hides the current_container and the value is not available in the next container (value returns undefined). But, when I call the getScores() in the constructor, the value is available ( I presume because, the constructor is called when the object is created and doesn't wait for the firing of the eventHandler )

Comment: Please edit your question to include **all** the necessary HTML and other scripts needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Dai I have now updated the post with a link to codepen. Please check

Answer (score -1):

you can call this.getScores() from the constructor, have you tried it?

````
constructor() {
       this.btn = document.getElementById("btn");
       this.score_display = document.getElementById("display");
       this.current_container = document.getElementById("current_container);
       this.next_container = document.getElementById("next_container);
       this.scores = document.querySelectorAll(".scores")

       this.finalScore;   //final score 


       // Event listeners
        this.eventListeners();

        this.getScores();
    }

```
````

Comment: Yes as I have mentioned in the post, it works. But I am trying to think of any other ways it can be achieved.